# 4WD robot platform turning problem

Tags: remote

I am trying bring up simple android controlled car using raspberry pi.

I tried following robot platform from sparkfun. I connected one L298N with 2 channels to control 4 motors. 2 motors from each side i connected to 2 channels. I don't see any problems in moving forward and reverse directions. But for turning left or right, somehow it is not working. For left, I am trying to reverse left motors and forward right motors. I tried on flat surface and carpet.. somehow looks like not motors doesn't have enough power to turn. Till now I tried 2 different robot platforms, both have similar issue.. I feel something wrong with my approach in turning. Can anyone please suggest better way to turn?

My [robot platform](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12090).

I tried [following robot platform](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GSIRHEU) also.

Answer (score 1):

On a 4WD, running two wheels forward and two backward will put a lot of sideways torque on the wheels. If they have a good grip, that might be enough to halt it completely. Try to have the wheels on one side going forwards very slowly, and the wheels on the other side a lot faster (like 2x or 3x faster), and see how that works out.